# Extracting confidence from scikit PassiveAggressiveClassifier() for single prediction

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have trained an `PassiveAggressiveClassifier` with a set of 165 categories.

Now I can already use it to predict certain inputs but it fails sometimes and it would be very helpful know how "confident" is the classifier on each prediction and what are the other considerations.

As far as I understand I get the distances for each category using `decision_function`

`distances = np.array(ppl.decision_function(sample))`

which gives me something like this for the distances:

```
[-1.4222 -1.5083 -2.6488 -2.3428 -1.3167 -3.9615 -2.7804 -1.9563 -0.5054
 -1.9524 -3.0026 -3.422  -2.1301 -2.0119 -2.1381 -2.2186 -2.0848 -2.4514
 -1.9478 -2.3101 -2.4044 -1.9155 -1.569  -1.31   -1.4865 -2.3251 -1.7773
 -1.304  -1.5215 -2.0634 -1.6987 -1.9217 -2.2863 -1.8166 -2.0219 -1.9594
 -1.747  -2.1503 -2.162  -1.9507 -1.5971 -3.4499 -1.8946 -2.4328 -2.2415
 -1.9045 -2.065  -1.9671 -1.8592 -1.6283 -1.7626 -2.2175 -2.1725 -3.7855
 -5.1397 -3.6485 -4.4072 -2.2109 -2.048  -2.4887 -2.2324 -2.7897 -1.2932
 -1.975  -1.516  -1.6127 -1.7135 -1.8243 -1.4887 -2.8973 -1.9656 -2.2236
 -2.2466 -2.1224 -1.2247 -1.9657 -1.6138 -2.7787 -1.5004 -2.0136 -1.1001
 -1.7226 -1.5829 -2.0317 -1.0834 -1.7444 -1.356  -2.3453 -1.7161 -2.2683
 -2.2725 -0.4512 -4.5038 -2.0386 -2.1849 -2.4256 -1.5678 -1.8114 -2.2138
 -2.2654 -1.8823 -2.7489 -1.8477 -2.1383 -1.6019 -2.84   -2.2595 -2.0764
 -1.6758 -2.4279 -2.3489 -2.1884 -2.1888 -1.6289 -1.7358 -1.2989 -1.5656
 -1.3362 -1.888  -2.1061 -1.4517 -2.0572 -2.4971 -2.2966 -2.6121 -2.4728
 -2.8977 -1.7571 -2.4363 -1.4775 -1.7144 -2.047  -3.9252 -1.9907 -2.1808
 -2.066  -1.9862 -1.4898 -2.3335 -2.6088 -2.4554 -2.4139 -1.7187 -2.2909
 -1.4846 -1.8696 -2.444  -2.6253 -1.7738 -1.7192 -1.8737 -1.9977 -1.9948
 -1.7667 -2.0704 -3.0147 -1.9014 -1.7713 -2.2551]
```

Now I have two questions:
1st whether it is possible to map the distances back to the categories since the length of the array (159) does not match my categories array.

2nd how can I calculate a confidence for the single prediction using the distances?

Comment: Are you sure your training set contained all 165 classes? If you did something like train_test_split without stratifying that could have resulted in your training set simply not containing the missing 6 classes (165 - 159).

Comment: ah yes, that's pretty possible, I used train_test_split()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Question 1**

As per the comment, make sure all your classes are contained in the training set. You can achieve this for example by using the `train_test_split` function and passing your targets into the `stratify` parameter.
Once you do this, the problem will disappear and there will be one classifier per each class. As a result, if you pass a sample to `decision_function` method there will be one distance to the hyperplane for each class.

**Question 2**

You can turn the distances into probabilities through rescaling and normalizing (i.e. softmax). This is already implemented internally in the `_predict_proba_lr` method. See the source code [here](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/a24c8b46/sklearn/linear_model/base.py#L331).